# How to add date to JMeter csv result file while running in command line mode

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

How can I add the actual date to the file name of a JMeter csv result file while running the test in command line mode?
E.g.

```
jmeter -n -t ~/tests/TP_Login_api.jmx -Jusers=12 -Jhost=devops1 -Juser_file=users_max.csv -Jaccount=max -l /results/results_TP_Login_api_${__time(yyyyMMdd-HHmmss)}.csv -e -o/results/report/TP_Login_api
```

Any ideas how dto achieve that?

Comment: Linux or windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In batch you need to work with batch syntax. For Bsh use:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
 jmeter -n -t ~/tests/TP_Login_api.jmx -Jusers=12 -Jhost=devops1 -Juser_file=users_max.csv -Jaccount=max -l /results/results_TP_Login_api_$NOW.csv -e -o/results/report/TP_Login_api
```

For windows see  [date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-datetime-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format).